# Format output file from paste command

Tags: awk, paste

I have two or more files

**FileA**

```
A: 18.49 RPKM    
C: 14.49 RPKM    
B: 18.89 RPKM
```

**FileB**

```
A: 21.29 RPKM    
C: 38.71 RPKM    
B: 36.13 RPKM
```

I want to paste these two files and print first-column only once and second column from each file

**Desired output (tab delimited)**

```
A:  18.49   21.29   
C:  14.49   38.71   
B:  18.89   36.13
```

I used the paste command

```
paste FileA FileB | awk '{ { print $1} {ORS="\t"} for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=3) { print $i } {print "\n"} }'
```

I get this output

A:

18.49   21.29

C:  14.49   38.71

B:  18.89   36.13

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue. thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box for any number of input files, all you need is:

```
$ paste FileA FileB | awk '{o=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i+=3) o=o"\t"$i; print o}'
A:      18.49   21.29
C:      14.49   38.71
B:      18.89   36.13
```

Answer (score 3):

`ORS` is the output *record* separator (which is usually a newline). That's why the first `{print $1}` gets a newline after it. Usually, you'd want to set `OFS`, the output field separator, for separating fields.

Instead of printing each field selectively, you can move the required fields to the start (so that column 5 (second column of second file) becomes column 3, column 8 (second column of third file) becomes column 4 and so on. Then you can reduce `NF` to delete the remaining, unnecessary columns.

```awk
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
{
  nfiles = NF / 3;  # get number of files
  for (i = 2; i <= nfiles; i++)  # second column is already OK, start from 3
    $(i+1) = $(3*i - 1);   # Assign 2nd column of file no. i to column no. i + 1
  NF = nfiles + 1 # set NF to delete remaining columns
}
1  # print lines
```

Example, with `FileC` and `FileD` being copies of B and A:

```
~ paste File* | awk -v OFS='\t' '{nfiles = NF / 3; for (i = 2; i <= nfiles; i++) $(i+1) = $(3*i - 1); NF = nfiles + 1} 1'
A:  18.49   21.29   21.29   18.49
C:  14.49   38.71   38.71   14.49
B:  18.89   36.13   36.13   18.89
```

Comment: The commands you wrote works, but is fixed with 2 input files. This is not always the case, as the number of input files varies, and do not want to write each column in awk script.

Comment: @CN_229133 try the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
join fileA fileB |awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3 }'.
```

Please ensure both files are sorted on identitical column.